# Flutter Hive not saving Subclasses

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Let's say I have following 3 Classes:

```
class Human{

    String name;

    Human({this.name});

}

class Student extends Human{

    int id;

    Student(this.id): super(name: name);
}

class Proffessor extends Human{

    int age;

    Proffessor(this.age): super(name: name);
}

class Abc {

    List<Human> humans;

    Abc(this.humans);
//Just Imagine my humans List consists of Proffessors AND Students (both Subtypes of human)
}
```

I am using following dependencies
hive_generator: ^1.1.1
hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
hive: ^2.0.4
dev_dependencies:
build_runner: ^2.1.4
Basically, I have a List that consits of Proffessors and Students but when this List is saved and later retrieved from Hive all Objects in that List are cast to Human

```
Abc read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();

    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) 
            reader.readByte(): reader.read(),  
    };

    return Abc(
        fields[0] as int,
        fields[1] as String?,
        fields[2] as String?,
        (fields[3] as List?)?.cast<Human>(), // I need the Elements in this List as Student / Proffessor not Human
        fields[4] as int,
    );}
```

//basically I am losing information because Students and Professors are cast to Human by the adapter

Is there a workaround to this? If not, whats the next best alternative to hive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is going on. I use hive like that

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class FavouriteSingerDao extends HiveObject{

 @HiveField(0)
  int id;

 @HiveField(2)
  String singerName;

 @HiveField(3)
  String singerTag;
 }
```

---

```
static Future addFavouriteSinger(SingerMapper favouriteSinger) async {
    final transaction = FavouriteSingerDao()
      ..id = favouriteSinger.id
      ..singerName = favouriteSinger.singerName
      ..singerTag = favouriteSinger.singerTag;

    final box = BoxesUtils.getFavouriteSingers();
    box.put(favouriteSinger.id, transaction).then(
          (value) => Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: TEXT_ADD_SUCCESS,
      ),
    );
  }

  static List<FavouriteSingerDao> getFavouriteSingerItems() {
    final box = BoxesUtils.getFavouriteSingers();
    List<FavouriteSingerDao> favouriteSingers =
    box.values.toList().cast<FavouriteSingerDao>();
    return favouriteSingers;
  }
```

Comment: You are not extending another Class, Hive works perfectly fine when I dont use subclasses my Problem is that when Hive retrieves the data it casts everything to Human although not everything in my List is Human, it is Student or Proffessor